# Bundle 0x Swaps

Tags: 0x

Is it possible to bundle swaps received by multiple `/swap/v1/quote` API requests?

Is there a deployed smart contract that provides the functionality to bundle multiple swaps and maybe even take care of the allowances beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

0x does not offer this capability. If you end up build it or found a project that has built it, would be interested to feature it.

Comment: I will investigate this in more detail and if I build it i'll let you know